# Parse json and search for property c#

Tags: c#, json

I have to log every request in our ASP.Net Web API project. When I log every request, I need to search for a property/token (PersonId) in the payload and persist it in the log table. The issue is the payload (or viewmodel) changes for every request, so I need to search for property for different payload. I am thinking of using SelectToken and pass the path to PersonId on every call. Is there any better way to get the value for different viewmodels/payload?

Comment: If you can modify the models, add an Interface, e.g., `IMissingPerson` which defines a `GetPersonId()` method. Implement the Interface, make the method return the `PersonId` of that model, so you know what to call no matter what model you deserialized your JSONs to. So, if a class doesn't implement the Interface, you can throw a `WhatTheHeckIsThisException`, so you know that a rogue model doesn't comply with the rules and you can fix it.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this is the existing project and making changes to each request payload would be difficult

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to determine if `PersonId` exists or get the value of it regardless where it is in the JSON?

```
JObject myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(myJsonReq);
var isPersonIdPresent = myObj[0].Children<JProperty>().Any(p => p.Name == "PersonId");
```

I wonder if it might be easier to just to search the string for `"PersonId"` or `"PersonId":`.

If you want the value of the element with `PersonId` as key:

```
var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJsonReqAsString);
string personIdValue = data["PersonId"].Value<string>();
```

Take a look at [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/queryinglinqtojson.htm) example using Newtonsoft.JSON.

Comment: I took a look at the link and I need to search for PersonId and get its value, but will data["PersonId"] work with all json as the json structure keeps changing with different viewmodel.

Comment: It should as long as it is a correct JSON format.

Comment: even if the payload is an an JSON array or if PersonId is in a different level, like "Person":{"Id": {"PersonId":123}}}

Comment: Using the bottom code snippet will result in this error: "*The name 'data' does not exist in the current context*". What namespace or context are you using that provides for `data[]`?

Comment: I am pretty sure it should be `jsonObj`.  Thank you for noticing the mistake.  I renamed both `data` to match the comments.